# SQL Server cannot use the "import Data" function

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Using SQL Sever Management Studio, I have tried to:

1. Right click the database.
2. Click "Task".
3. Click "Import Data".

However, nothing show up... It used to be working :(

Desperately need a help, please help everyone! thank you so much!!

[image]

Comment: have you tried to close everything? or even restarted your workstation?

Comment: Yes, i have. Still not working :(

Comment: try this execute manually "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\DTSWizard.exe"

Comment: It poped with "Invalid license data. Reinstall is required." However, i have many database in sql, afraid after reinstall, my data will be gone and time many time to restore data again... :(

Do you know any other ways thank you so much!!

Comment: And it shown in  SQL:

The SSIS Runtime object could not be created. Verify that DTS.dll is available and registered. The wizard cannot continue and it will terminate.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {8BF6572D-674B-494E-9047-DDD0E24BB785} failed due to the following error: 8007007e The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E). (DTSWizard)

Comment: you need to reinstall your sql management studio

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Import/Export wizard is installed and available (as shown in screenshot), try to restart PC if it's pending from any installation part.

[image]

It would be available by default if the SQL services installed, in case not available, you can install it via [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/install-integration-services?view=sql-server-2017)